# Google Maps Directions API Calculating Incorrect Route

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, flask

I'm creating a web application using Flask and the Google Maps Directions API, where I ask the user to enter a starting point, waypoints, and a destination, and pass this data to the Google API to render a map illustrating the user's route. No matter what these data points are, however, the API keeps interpreting all 3 data points as a single location, and renders the map accordingly. The rendered map is 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5AzR.png), where you can also see what this exact wrong address is.

The relevant source files are as follows:
run.py (where I call my template to render the Google Map in the "/finalize_new_trip" route):

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from flask import flash, Flask, Markup, redirect, render_template, url_for, request
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

import os
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
import json

_cwd = dirname(abspath(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = 'flask-session-insecure-secret-key'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + join(_cwd, 'TripLogger.db')
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY = 'this-should-be-more-random' #TODO: RANDOMIZE THIS KEY


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Trip(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'trips'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    trip_name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    origin = db.Column(db.String)
    destination = db.Column(db.String)
    waypoints = db.Column(db.String) #SEE IF ANOTHER DATA TYPE IS BETTER- IDEALLY WANT TO STORE LIST OF STRINGS

    def __init__(self, trip_name, origin, destination, waypoints):
        self.trip_name = trip_name
        self.origin = origin
        self.destination = destination
        self.waypoints = waypoints

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Trip %r(name = %r, origin = %r, destination = %r)>' % (self.id, self.trip_name, self.origin, self.destination)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trip_name

#CONSIDER CUSTOM VALIDATORS TO ENSURE THAT TRIP_NAME IS UNIQUE FOR A SPECIFIC USER/ACCOUNT
class TripForm(FlaskForm):
    trip_name = StringField('Trip Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    origin = StringField('Origin', validators=[DataRequired()])
    destination = StringField('Destination', validators=[DataRequired()])
    waypoints = StringField('Waypoint')

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    trip_form = TripForm(request.form)
    if trip_form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Submitted new trip form, now redirecting to /finalize_new_trip to render map...")
        return redirect(url_for("complete_trip", trip_name = trip_form.trip_name.data, origin = trip_form.origin.data, destination = trip_form.destination.data, waypoints = trip_form.waypoints.data))
    return render_template("index.html", trip_form = trip_form)

# Route to display trip on map (in future, to modify trip details, e.g. waypoints)
@app.route("/finalize_new_trip", methods=["POST"])
def complete_trip():
    return render_template("finish_new_trip.html", trip_name = request.args.get("trip_name"), origin = request.args.get("origin"), destination = request.args.get("destination"), waypoints = request.args.get("waypoints"))

# Store new trip data in database
@app.route("/store_trip", methods=["POST"])
def store_trip():
    trip_data = request.form("trip_data")
    return json.loads(trip_data)[0]

def query_to_list(query, include_field_names=True):
    """Turns a SQLAlchemy query into a list of data values."""
    column_names = []
    for i, obj in enumerate(query.all()):
        if i == 0:
            column_names = [c.name for c in obj.__table__.columns]
            if include_field_names:
                yield column_names
        yield obj_to_list(obj, column_names)


def obj_to_list(sa_obj, field_order):
    """Takes a SQLAlchemy object - returns a list of all its data"""
    return [getattr(sa_obj, field_name, None) for field_name in field_order]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

finish_new_trip.html (the template using the Google Maps API to render the map):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=<MY_API_KEY>&callback=getOriginCoordinates" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <title>Finish New Trip</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="trip_name"> 
      <h1> {{ trip_name }} </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="right-panel">
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="submit" id="finish-new-trip-button" value="Add My Trip!">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="directions-panel"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      //Wrapper function to AJAX POST request that passes data back to server.
      /*function passTripData() {
        document.getElementById("finish-new-trip-button").onclick = function() {
          // Retrieve data from displayed map (after user makes changes) after testing
          $.post( "{{ url_for('store_trip') }}", {
            trip_data: {
              "trip_name": "{{ trip_name }}",
              "origin": "{{ origin }}",
              "destination": "{{ destination }}",
              "waypoints": [
                "{{ waypoints }}"
              ]
            } 
          });  
        }
      }*/

      //Use Geocoding API to get coordinates for origin, destination, and waypoints.
      function getOriginCoordinates() {
        //passTripData(); // function that sets onClick event for "Submit" button
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "{{ origin }}"}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            originCoordinates = results[0].geometry.location;
            console.log("Origin coords: " + "lat = " + originCoordinates.lat() + ", lng = " + originCoordinates.lng());
            getDestCoordinates(originCoordinates);
          } else {
            alert('Geocode of origin was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
      function getDestCoordinates(originCoords) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "{{ destination }}"}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            destCoordinates = results[0].geometry.location;
            console.log("Dest coords: " + "lat = " + destCoordinates.lat() + ", lng = " + destCoordinates.lng());
            getWaypointCoordinates(originCoords, destCoordinates);
          } else {
            alert('Geocode of destination was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
      function getWaypointCoordinates(originCoords, destCoords) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "{{ waypoints }}"}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            waypointCoordinates = results[0].geometry.location;
            console.log("Waypoint coords: " + "lat = " + waypointCoordinates.lat() + ", lng = " + waypointCoordinates.lng());
            initMap(originCoords, destCoords, waypointCoordinates);
          } else {
            alert('Geocode of waypoints was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

      function initMap(originCoords, destCoords, waypointCoords) {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

        //Center map between origin and destination.
        //TEST LATLNG OBJECTS FIRST
        console.log("Origin: lat=" + originCoords.lat() + ", lng=" + originCoords.lng());
        console.log("Destination: lat=" + destCoords.lat() + ", lng=" + destCoords.lng());

        var mapLatitudeCenter = (originCoords.lat() + destCoords.lat())/2;
        var mapLongitudeCenter = (originCoords.lng() + destCoords.lng())/2;

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {lat: mapLatitudeCenter, lng: mapLongitudeCenter}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, originCoords, destCoords, waypointCoords);
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, originCoords, destCoords, waypointCoords) {
        var waypts = [];
        waypts.push({
          location: waypointCoords,
          stopover: true
        });

        directionsService.route({
          origin: originCoords,
          destination: destCoords,
          waypoints: waypts,
          optimizeWaypoints: true,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route = response.routes[0];
            var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
            summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
            // For each route, display summary information.
            for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
              var routeSegment = i + 1;
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
                  '</b><br>';
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I test my app locally, the console displays the latitude/longitude coordinates of each data point (origin, destination, and waypoints), and they all correspond to this incorrect address in Italy. I also previously received a "404" error message, but I am not receiving that now.

I attempted to regenerate my API key and use this new key, but this didn't fix the problem. How can I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I change `complete_trip():` to

```
@app.route("/finalize_new_trip", methods=["GET"])
def complete_trip():
    return render_template("finish_new_trip.html", trip_name ='new trip', origin='new york, ny', destination='los angeles, california', waypoints='topeka, kansas')
```

and request the page, the results are perfect (a trip from NY to LA that goes through Topeka). You've got a lot of commented out code everywhere. I have a feeling that somewhere you're not getting the data you expect (for example, we can't see the form HTML used to post this data).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I checked your method and manually entering these addresses worked for me as well. I resolved this by making this change to a GET request for this endpoint, and updating my route URL to include my parameters as follows: `@app.route("/finalize_new_trip/<trip_name>/<origin>/<destination>/<waypoints>", methods=["GET"])` and my API requests are now working.

Comment: For your reference, my form HTML template is: `{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% import "helpers/forms.html" as forms %}

{% block title %} Welcome to TripLogger! {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{{ super() }}

<p> Planning a new trip? </p>
<p> Start by entering some basic information below. </p>

<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="POST">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Create New Trip</legend>
  {{ forms.render(trip_form) }}
  <p><input type="Submit" value="Finish Creating Trip"></p>
 </fieldset>
</form>

{% endblock content %}`